# ¿Cómo solventar el problema PLS-00049 en un trigger que intenta hacer una auditoria?

Tags: oracle

tengo un problema con un "trigger" que estoy intentando realizar, es como una especie de Auditoria. Es decir, que cuando actualice, o elimine datos de la tabla "Visitas", la información que tenía antes y la nueva, se vea registrada en mi tabla de "AUDI_VISITAS".

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE  "VISITAS" 
   (    "COD_VISITA" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "ID_ET" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "ID_MIEMBRO" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "FECHAVISITA" DATE, 
    "OBSERVACIONES" VARCHAR2(150), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("COD_VISITA")
)

CREATE TABLE  "AUDI_VISITAS" 
   (    "COD_VISITA" NUMBER, 
    "ID_ET" NUMBER, 
    "ID_MIEMBRO_NUEVO" NUMBER, 
    "ID_MIEMBRO_ANTIGUO" NUMBER, 
    "FECHAVISITA_NUEVA" DATE, 
    "FECHAVISITA_ANTIGUA" DATE, 
    "OBSERVACIONES_NUEVAS" VARCHAR2(150), 
    "OBSERVACIONES_ANTIGUAS" VARCHAR2(150), 
    "DIRECCION_IP" VARCHAR2(30)
   )

CREATE TABLE  "EQUIPO_TRABAJO" 
   (    "ID_ET" NUMBER, 
    "CEDULA_ET" NUMBER, 
    "NOMBRES_ET" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "APELLIDOS_ET" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "CELULAR_ET" NUMBER, 
    "FECHANACIMIENTO_ET" DATE, 
    "CORREO_ET" VARCHAR2(40), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID_ET")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )

CREATE TABLE  "MIEMBROS" 
   (    "ID_MIEMBRO" NUMBER, 
    "CEDULA_M" NUMBER, 
    "NOMBRES_M" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "APELLIDOS_M" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "DIRECCION_M" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "CELULAR_M" NUMBER, 
    "CORREO_M" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "GENERO_M" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "BAUTIZADO" VARCHAR2(5), 
    "COD_ESTADO_CIVIL" NUMBER, 
    "COD_RANGO_EDAD" NUMBER, 
    "FECHANACIMIENTO_M" DATE, 
    "WHATSAPP" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "COD_MINISTERIO" NUMBER, 
    "COD_ESCUELA_FORMACION" NUMBER, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID_MIEMBRO")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
```

El código del trigger que estoy intentando hacer es el siguiente:

```
create or replace TRIGGER AUDITO_VISITAS 
    after update or delete on VISITAS
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   for each row
 BEGIN
        if not dbms_utility.format_call_stack like ('%TR_MIEMBROS%') then
            IF UPDATING THEN
                INSERT INTO AUDI_VISITAS VALUES(:NEW.COD_VISITA, :NEW.ID_ET, :NEW.ID_MIEMBRO_NUEVO, :OLD.ID_MIEMBRO_ANTIGUO, :NEW.FECHAVISITA_NUEVA, :OLD.FECHAVISITA_ANTIGUA, 
                :NEW.OBSERVACIONES_NUEVAS, :OLD.OBSERVACIONES_ANTIGUAS, sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'));
          
            ELSIF DELETING THEN
                INSERT INTO AUDI_VISITAS VALUES(:NEW.COD_VISITA, :NEW.ID_ET, :NEW.ID_MIEMBRO_NUEVO,  :OLD.ID_MIEMBRO_ANTIGUO, :NEW.FECHAVISITA_NUEVA, :OLD.FECHAVISITA_ANTIGUA, 
                NEW.OBSERVACIONES_NUEVAS, OLD.OBSERVACIONES_ANTIGUAS, sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'));
            END IF;
        end if;
      
        if not dbms_utility.format_call_stack like ('%TR_EQUIPO_TRABAJO%') then
            IF UPDATING THEN
                INSERT INTO AUDI_VISITAS VALUES(:NEW.COD_VISITA, NEW.ID_ET, :NEW.ID_MIEMBRO_NUEVO, :OLD.ID_MIEMBRO_ANTIGUO, :NEW.FECHAVISITA_NUEVA, :OLD.FECHAVISITA_ANTIGUA, 
                :NEW.OBSERVACIONES_NUEVAS, :OLD.OBSERVACIONES_ANTIGUAS, sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'));
          
            ELSIF DELETING THEN
                INSERT INTO AUDI_VISITAS VALUES(:NEW.COD_VISITA, :NEW.ID_ET, :NEW.ID_MIEMBRO_NUEVO, :OLD.ID_MIEMBRO_ANTIGUO, :NEW.FECHAVISITA_NUEVA, :OLD.FECHAVISITA_ANTIGUA, 
                :NEW.OBSERVACIONES_NUEVAS, :OLD.OBSERVACIONES_ANTIGUAS, sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'));
            END IF;
        end if;
 END;
```

Pero, al ejecutar el trigger me sale la siguiente lista de errores:

```
Error en la línea 4: PLS-00049: la variable de enlace 'NEW.ID_MIEMBRO_NUEVO' es errónea
Error en la línea 4: PLS-00049: la variable de enlace 'OLD.ID_MIEMBRO_ANTIGUO' es errónea
Error en la línea 4: PLS-00049: la variable de enlace 'NEW.FECHAVISITA_NUEVA' es errónea
Error en la línea 4: PLS-00049: la variable de enlace 'OLD.FECHAVISITA_ANTIGUA' es errónea
Error en la línea 5: PLS-00049: la variable de enlace 'NEW.OBSERVACIONES_NUEVAS' es errónea
Error en la línea 14: PLS-00049: la variable de enlace 'OLD.OBSERVACIONES_ANTIGUAS' es errónea
Error en la línea 13: PLS-00049: la variable de enlace 'NEW.ID_MIEMBRO_NUEVO' es errónea
Error en la línea 13: PLS-00049: la variable de enlace 'OLD.ID_MIEMBRO_ANTIGUO' es errónea
Error en la línea 13: PLS-00049: la variable de enlace 'NEW.FECHAVISITA_NUEVA' es errónea
Error en la línea 13: PLS-00049: la variable de enlace 'OLD.FECHAVISITA_ANTIGUA' es errónea
Error en la línea 14: PLS-00049: la variable de enlace 'NEW.OBSERVACIONES_NUEVAS' es errónea
Error en la línea 5: PLS-00049: la variable de enlace 'OLD.OBSERVACIONES_ANTIGUAS' es errónea
```

Agradezco de antemano si alguien puede ayudarme con este problema.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! la tabla Visitas no tiene el campo ID_MIEMBRO_NUEVO, entonces no puede venir nunca en new, porque ahi viene lo que se va a agregar a la tabla que ejecuta el trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu trigger es sobre la tabla `visitas`. Es `after update or delete`.

Tus variables `:old` y `:new` hacen referencia a los registros previo y nuevo en el update / delete sobre `visitas`. Por lo tanto, no tienes campos de las otras tablas en esas variables porque son registros de esa tabla.

¿Qué sería el dato de :OLD.OBSERVACIONES_ANTIGUAS que insertas? Sabiendo que no lo tienes en la tabla VISITAS. Si es el campo OBSERVACIONES, entonces úsalo como es.

```
create or replace TRIGGER AUDITO_VISITAS 
    after update or delete on VISITAS
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   for each row
 BEGIN
        if not dbms_utility.format_call_stack like ('%TR_MIEMBROS%') then
            IF UPDATING THEN
                INSERT INTO AUDI_VISITAS VALUES(:NEW.COD_VISITA, :NEW.ID_ET, :NEW.ID_MIEMBRO, :OLD.ID_MIEMBRO, :NEW.FECHAVISITA, :OLD.FECHAVISITA, 
                :NEW.OBSERVACIONES, :OLD.OBSERVACIONES, sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'));
          
            ELSIF DELETING THEN
...
```

Tienes que llamar los campos de VISITAS. Al decirle INSERT INTO AUDI_VISITAS VALUES, le estás dando el orden de los campos en la tabla AUDI_VISITAS. Si le das nombres inventados, la BD no sabe de dónde sacar esos datos.

Si quieres ir más tranquilo y que sea más legible, el insert puede ser

```
INSERT INTO AUDI_VISITAS (
COD_VISITA, ID_ET, ID_MIEMBRO_NUEVO, 
ID_MIEMBRO_ANTIGUO, FECHAVISITA_NUEVA, FECHAVISITA_ANTIGUA,
 OBSERVACIONES_NUEVAS, OBSERVACIONES_ANTIGUAS, 
DIRECCION_IP)
VALUES(:NEW.COD_VISITA, :NEW.ID_ET, :NEW.ID_MIEMBRO, 
:OLD.ID_MIEMBRO, :NEW.FECHAVISITA, :OLD.FECHAVISITA, 
 :NEW.OBSERVACIONES, :OLD.OBSERVACIONES, 
sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'));
```

Lo que no tiene sentido es que le digas *tráeme el campo observaciones_nuevas de la tabla visitas* porque la BD no tiene cómo responder a esa solicitud. En el INSERT INTO dices **a dónde van los datos** y en el VALUES dices **qué datos vas a mandar allá**.

Comment: Hola, gracias por preguntar y ayudarme.

":OLD.OBSERVACIONES_ANTIGUAS" haría referencia al parámetro "Observaciones" en la tabla VISITAS, es decir, lo que intento que se guarde allí es el valor o lo que se había guardado allí después de hacer el UPDATE. 

No sé si me hice entender.

Comment: @StivenRodriguez respuesta editada

Comment: Woow, ¡muchísimas gracias @Alfabravo!, me funciona el trigger en optimas condiciones.